# SOAP Service Connection returning image URL with a comma at the end

Tags: list, soap, data-form-web-part

I am using SOAP Service connection to connect to a list in another sharepoint in the collection.  (Sharepoint 2010)

All of the data comes over fine, except one field which is an image.  The URLs all seem to have a , at the end.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ows_Icon" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
or
<img border="0" src="{@ows_Icon}" />
```

Both return a URL like the following:

'https://www.site.com/directory/ico_people.jpg,'

Any idea how to remove the , so that I can show the image in the subsite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<img border="0" src="{substring-before(@ows_Icon, ',')}" />
```

The comma is there because image fields have 2 fields associated with it, a URL and a description.